# I am trying to configure nginx as proxy server but getting an error while composing docker file

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to configure nginx as proxy server but getting an error. I have created below file as part of my work.

DockerFile

```
 FROM nginx:1.10.1-alpine
 RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
 COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Proxy.config

```
server {

listen 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;

}
}
```

docker-compose.yml

---

```
version: '2'

services:
app:
    build: app

proxy:
    build: proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

When I build docker-compose file I am getting following error:

```
Puja:Docker pujadudhat$ docker-compose build
Building app
Step 1/2 : FROM nginx:1.10.1-alpine
---> 2cd900f340dd

Step 2/2 : COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
---> Using cache
---> 9d105a18fb9d
Successfully built 9d105a18fb9d
Building proxy

Step 1/3 : FROM nginx:1.10.1-alpine
---> 2cd900f340dd  
Step 2/3 : RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
---> Using cache
---> a4e1efc3f050
Step 3/3 : COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ERROR: Service 'proxy' failed to build: lstat proxy.conf: no such file or directory
```

I am getting this error "Service 'proxy' failed to build: lstat proxy.conf: no such file or directory. Can anyone help me to solve? Thank you.n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the proxy.conf in your project where you build the docker container. It looks like you have it named **Proxy.conf** and it should be named **proxy.conf**.

Comment: When I try to mount config file. I get an error.  which is below

Comment: Puja:Dockers pujadudhat$ docker run --name my-nginx -d -v /Users/Puja Dudhat/Dockers/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.2-alpin

Comment: docker: Error parsing reference: "Dudhat/Dockers/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: You should not have to mount a configuration file. What are you trying to do in the configuration file?

Comment: Background information about volumes; that is, linking to permanent server content from your container:

Docker allows us to link directories from our virtual machine's local file system to our containers.

Comment: $ docker run --name my-custom-nginx-container -v /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx

Comment: But getting an error. See my command above. I typed same as in official doc

Comment: Do you have a container names **my-custom-nginx-container**. Is there a space in the path after the **-v** option. You might want to double quote the path name like this: docker run --name my-nginx -d -v "/Users/Puja Dudhat/Dockers/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro" -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.2-alpin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138579/discussion-between-pooja-gajera-and-srayhunter).